# How does the get_list tastypie function work?

Tags: python, django, serialization, tastypie

I'm trying to use the get_list tastypie function but I can't make it work. I've looked for documentation about that but I can't find it.

Whatever, I've a list of item ids and an ItemResource. I'm trying to return a list of serialized objects.
So I just want to do something like that :

```
item_resource = ItemResource()
item_ids = my_item_id_list
return item_resource.get_list(request, id=item_ids)
```

But of course it's not working.
What would be the correct syntax to do that ?

Thx !

Comment: Is `item_resource` a `ModelResource` or `Resource`?

Comment: can you please explain why are you trying to use the method directly?

Comment: I'm actually trying to understand exactly how tastypie works, so I can make my own made functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your `ItemResource` accepts `filters` (more [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.16/resources.html#filtering)), you have to copy-paste all the stuff from [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.16/tastypie/resources.py#L1306), lines #1306 - #1313.

The point is that `get_list` results get filtered only by `obj_get_list` (initial filters), and `apply_filters` (request-specific filters) so you have to skip directly to the serialization part (you can include the pagination part, if needed).

This is one of the cases where `django-restframework` appears to be better than `django-tastypie` - it refactores serialization out into a separate class, avoiding the code duplication.